# how to bind HTML5 and SpringMVC 4 using Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, thymeleaf

OK, I managed to get my application using Thymeleaf and now I need to reconstruct all the JSP pages into HTML5. First and foremost, I need to be able to login into the application using the username and password that worked very nicely on JSP.

My bean for assigning the HTML5 pages as the view layer is defined as:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/html/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");

    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(engine);

    return viewResolver;
}
```

My LoginController is defined as:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    UserProfileService userProfileService;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String homePage(ModelMap model) {
        String user = getPrincipal();
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hi, Welcome to HRM");
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("roles", initializeProfiles());
    return "welcome";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage() {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null){    
            new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
        }
    return "redirect:/login?logout";
    }

    private String getPrincipal(){
        String userName = null;
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            userName = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            userName = principal.toString();
        }
        return userName;
    }
(...)
}
```

The old `login.jsp` is transcribed bellow:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@include file="include/include.jsp"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Login page</title>
        <%@include file="include/imports.jsp"%>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="mainWrapper">
            <div class="login-container">
                <div class="login-card">
                    <div class="login-form">
                        <c:url var="loginUrl" value="/login" />
                        <form action="${loginUrl}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                            <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <p>Invalid username and password.</p>
                                </div>
                            </c:if>
                            <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
                                <div class="alert alert-success">
                                    <p>You have been logged out successfully. </p>
                                </div>
                            </c:if>
                            <div class="input-group input-sm">
                                <label class="input-group-addon" for="username"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="ssoId" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group input-sm">
                                <label class="input-group-addon" for="password"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></label> 
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"  value="${_csrf.token}" />

                            <div class="form-actions">
                                <input type="submit"
                                class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-default" value="Log in">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

The new `login.html` is transcribed bellow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
<title>Login Page</title>

<meta name="description" content="login page" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<!-- <link rel="imports" href="include/imports.html" /> -->

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/favicon.png"
type="image/x-icon" />

<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link id="bootstrap-rtl-link" href="" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link
href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,400,600,700,300"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link id="beyond-link" href="assets/css/beyond.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="assets/css/demo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="assets/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link id="skin-link" href="" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="assets/js/skins.min.js" ></script>

<script src="assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

<script src="assets/js/beyond.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="login-container animated fadeInDown">
        <div class="loginbox bg-white">
            <div class="loginbox-title">SIGN IN</div>

            <div class="loginbox-textbox">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="loginbox-textbox">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="loginbox-forgot">
                <a href="">Forgot Password?</a>
            </div>
            <div class="loginbox-submit">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Login"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="loginbox-signup">
                <a href="register.html">Sign Up With Email</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I really am not familiar with how Thymeleaf and HTML5 handles requests. On the JSP form, the action was explicit and the submit type button or link would access the POST method on the controller and process the request. But how do I bind the view (Thymeleaf + HTML5) to the controller (Spring) layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, you have a form with both action and method attributes specified in your JSP template, but you're lacking a form entirely in your Thymeleaf template. You should be able to re-create the same form with either th:attr, th:action or th:method attributes. With properly mapped request, your controller should handle it no problem.

For more details, you can have a look at section 5 of Thymeleaf docs:
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-attribute-values